# I need to add images and dropdown's fields into attributes in magento

Tags: image, magento, field, addattribute

I need to add images and dropdown's fields  into attributes(catalog/attributes/Manage Attributes/..) in magento.

Like this
[image]

In fronted it's must be like this
[image]

How it's can to make?

Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not added field into attribute. I created the table with fields:
id
attribute_code (color, size, etc..)
style(radio, swatch, checkbox,..)
image

now it's like this
[image]